# Powershell does not render my script help correctly

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script with rather a big help at the beginning of it to be displayed with the `Get-Help` command - https://gist.github.com/MarkKharitonov/91698caf8c695902eacde2b6c7825bf1

I have two problems with the way the help is rendered. Specifically with the `.EXAMPLE` section. Here is an abbreviated version of the help (see the hyperlink for the full version of the script and the help):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Runs a WinDBG command or a script file.

...

.NOTES
    The default is to scan for images using the .imgscan /l. One has to check first with the WinDBG GUI to see if this is necessary, because this is a time consuming operation.

.EXAMPLE
    Please, find below a PowerShell session transcript showing the script invoked with the -Command parameter:

    PS D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017> cat C:\Users\mkharitonov\runcdb.config.ps1
    $Sosex = "E:\Utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll"
    $CDB = "e:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe"
    $SymbolsCache = "E:\Symbols"
    PS D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017> cat .\runcdb.config.ps1
    $dump = "d:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017\Quartz.Server.DMP"
    $ImagePath = "d:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017\BJE"
    $NoScanForImages = $false
    PS D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017> runcdb.ps1 -Command "!dumpheap -mt 00007fff11d90f78 -live"
    ...        
    PS D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017>

    The script produced two log files:
    c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\!dumpheap_-mt_00007fff11d90f78_-live.log.init 
    c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\!dumpheap_-mt_00007fff11d90f78_-live.log

    Here is the WinDBG code executed by the script:
    | .logopen "c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\!dumpheap_-mt_00007fff11d90f78_-live.log.init"
    | .imgscan /l
    | .load E:\Utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll
    | !lhi
    | .logclose
    | .logopen "c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\!dumpheap_-mt_00007fff11d90f78_-live.log"
    | !dumpheap -mt 00007fff11d90f78 -live
    | .logclose
    | q
#>
```

**Problem 1**

Notice that the last lines start with **|**. This is because of `.logopen` - PowerShell attempts to treat it as a help section keyword, like `.NOTES` or `.EXAMPLE`. Of course, there is no such keyword and so PowerShell just truncates the help output and stops short of showing the last lines. I had to escape the dot somehow, but could not figure out the way.

**Problem 2**

Please, observe:
[image]

Notice the **C:\PS>** in the output. Of course, it is not part of my help.

So, two questions - how to escape the first dot in a help line and what is the source of the **C:\PS>** in the help output above?

Comment: My guess is that this is a "by design" thing.  I would think this would be more of a `.NOTES` entry than a `.EXAMPLE` entry.  The script header is extremely poorly documented, so I doubt you'll find much help on this.

Comment: Seems like it's a bug or redesign on Microsoft's side. Even following [***their docs***](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458353.aspx) I end up with your issue, contrary to their screenshot. It seems to insert the prompt on the first line of the example body, unless you have the `>` character

Comment: As far as `.logopen` is concerned, I do not see your issue, at least on version `5.1.15063.502`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem 1 - (lines beginning with dot `.`)

I don't think there's any getting around this with *comment based* help, but if you use [*XML based help*](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-help/writing-xml-help-for-advanced-functions) then I don't think it would be an issue. That's a big change though.

## Problem 2 - (prompt string)

It seems to do this with all examples, and isn't likely to be avoided with XML help. For what it's worth, I don't like this behavior either.

However, I will say that your example, I think, does not properly follow the format of what an example is. Your explanation that looks awkward in front of a prompt shouldn't be in the example section.

After `.EXAMPLE` you should just put the line of code (a short explanation could maybe go after the code).

More explanation can be given in `.NOTES`, or in linked documentation.