# Is it possible to provide a custom title for an example section in the Powershell script help string?

Tags: powershell

Right now the example sections are numbered. I would like them to have my own custom titles.

I have a PS script with the help here - https://gist.github.com/MarkKharitonov/91698caf8c695902eacde2b6c7825bf1

There are three examples there. The first one is:

```
.EXAMPLE
    cd "D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017"
    #############
    # The User Config File
    #############

    PS D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017> cat C:\Users\mkharitonov\runcdb.config.ps1
    $Sosex = "E:\Utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll"
    $CDB = "e:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe"
    $SymbolsCache = "E:\Symbols"
```

And it is rendered like this:

```
-------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

C:\PS>cd "D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017"

#############
# The User Config File
#############

PS D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017> cat C:\Users\mkharitonov\runcdb.config.ps1
$Sosex = "E:\Utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll"
$CDB = "e:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe"
$SymbolsCache = "E:\Symbols"
```

Not ideal. I would like **The User Config File** to be the example title. However, I cannot just have it immediately under .EXAMPLE, because then PowerShell prepends it with **PS C:>** - see [Powershell does not render my script help correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600799/powershell-does-not-render-my-script-help-correctly)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible with the current help system.

Comment: Can you recommend another way to structure my examples so that I could provide both example code and some further explanations/title per example?

Comment: @mark I don't think the current help system allows for that. As I mentioned in your other post, I think you should keep the `.EXAMPLE` section sparse; a line of code, and maybe a short explanation. Caveats and some other use cases go in `.NOTES`, anything else, link to it with one or more `.LINK` sections.

Comment: @mark further, I don't think that you should shoehorn the extra info in sections with the goal of getting it to _display_ the way you want. The output of `Get-Help` is not just for human consumption; it's a series of objects and properties that can (and sometimes is) parsed by automated processes, so subverting that is not good practice.